# Integrating $f(x,y)dx$ for unknown $y$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Is there a way to express an integral such as

$$\int (2-y)x^{y-2}dx$$ where $y\equiv y(x)$ we don't know what $y$ is. Is there a way to do this type of integral or do we have to know $y(x)$.

Comment: You cannot evaluate the integral without knwoung what $y(x)$ is.

Comment: Even if $y=a+ b x$ you cannot